# Data Explorer operation for request ID's [93848f5ec2fa6a0865cdsXXX] timed out after 45 secs Check your query and try again?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

MongoDB Cloud > Cluster > Collections > Not loading documents
(when I fill the form on web page it needs to be saved on database ryt? Saving but not getting to load or I can't See my collections)
But Applications works fine.

Expecting right solutions [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nzHG.png)enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me tonight, same situation, app worked fine etc. I was able to get past this error by clicking on another collection in Atlas and then clicking back on to the collection that was giving me the error originally.

Also try restarting your browser, or even your computer if none of the above works.

Comment: Ya but now I'm getting, (Ask me how?)only ONCE after deleting 
 existing database on MongoDB collections and filling my form once again in web browser then it will create new database with same existing db name, open it and there u can C ur db.